# Mongo Aggregation self referencing object operations

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I need to perform an Aggregation operation in mongo which requires accessing a field name which is unknown at query time. Here's an example data set:

```
{
  leader: 'bob',
  members: {
    bob: 5.7,
    alice: 8.2,
    charlie: 2.1
  },
  score: 9
},
{
  leader: 'fred',
  members: {
    june: 5.7,
    daisy: 8.2,
    fred: 2.1
  },
  score: 3
},
{
  leader: 'tuna',
  members: {
    bob: 0.7,
    alice: 1.2,
    tuna: 2.1
  },
  score: 4
}
```

I need to be able to multiply the team leader score via the team score. So for example the first data point would be bob (5.7) X score (9). The leader name is declared in the `leader` field. Unfortunately my attempts to use a variable field name in the aggregation framework have all failed. The expected output would be something like:

```
{
  score: 51.3
},
{
  score: 6.3
},
{
  score: 8.4
}
```

What expressions I have tried so far:

```
'$members[bob]' => null
'$members.bob' => 5.7, but we can't hardcode this as bob is unknown
'$members[$leader]' => null
'$members.$leader' => $ name exception error
'$members.$$CURRENT.leader' => $ name exception error
'$members[$$CURRENT.leader]' => null
```

I suspect that there may be some clever projection to get around this, or maybe $let can do something magical, but I am not familiar enough with $let to figure out a way.

Comment: You should use mapReduce. Did you consider making "members" an array of documents?

Comment: This dataset is multiple years old, contains several million records, and cannot be modified. MapReduce is a possibility, but I'd rather use aggregation due to it being more much more performant as this data is being actively used in a realtime application.

Comment: According to https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-23310, this request may not be able to be done in current aggregate framework.